# npm not working on windows - Error: Cannot find module 'emoji-regex'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I was trying to update the version of npm and I don't know what went wrong but since then no command of npm is working (globally as well as inside any folder). I can't do `npm install`, or even `npm -v` I have tried uninstalling and installing node, updating node versions, using previous versions but nothing works. It gives me the following error:

```
 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'emoji-regex'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\string-width\index.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\wide-truncate.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\render-template.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\plumbing.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gauge\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\lib\log.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\log-shim.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\node_modules\←[4mgauge←[24m\node_modules\←[4mstring-width←[24m\index.js:4:20)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\node_modules\\string-width\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\wide-truncate.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\render-template.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\plumbing.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\gauge\\lib\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\lib\\log.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\log-shim.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\exit-handler.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\nihal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

I tried `where node` and `where npm` and they give these results respectively:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe 

C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\nihal\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you ran a simple hello world?

Comment: @dcolazin run where? From terminal, I can run my entire node js project with all dependencies. I have to do `node app.js`, I can't do `npm start` because anything with npm doesn't work.

Comment: then the Error: Cannot find module 'emoji-regex' might not be that relevant to understand what's happening. what error do you receive with npm start with a simple hello world?

Comment: @dcolazin the same error. `Error: Cannot find module 'emoji-regex'` . Doesn't matter from where I do or what npm command I use. I still get the same error.

Comment: @dcolazin hi, thanks for your time and effort. I finally was able to solve this. If interested, I have posted the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after several trial and errors, I was finally able to solve this. These where the steps I followed:

1. Use `where node` and `where npm` to know their locations.
2. Uninstall Nodejs
3. Manually delete all the folders which I found in step 1 (If they are still there. For me, they were).
4. Install latest Nodejs

Now everything works.
Thanks!